# Product of matrices coming from bases of free abelian groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I am reading a line in Stewart and Tall's Algebraic Number Theory text that I am unsure about. Suppose $G$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$ and $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ are both bases. Then there exist integers $a_{ij},b_{ij}$ such that $y_i=\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$ and $x_i=\sum_j a_{ij}y_j$. Consider the matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$. The book claims that $AB=I_n$, the identity matrix. Why is this true?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Stewart Algebraic Number Theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the composition of inverse change of basis matrices, and so is the identity.